# Aws Lambda display progress

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-lambda

I want to have a lambda function to run batch payment jobs.

When the user send the batch job. I want the user to see the progress of batch payment. So I want the Lambda function to send the messages back to the client. The user needs to see what payment was successful too.

I expect the lambda function will take around 3-5 minutes to run.

What should I use to for Lambda to communicate with the client side code? Sockets? The client side is written in Vuejs.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

An AWS Lambda function cannot 'return' information while it is running.

It can, however, periodically 'send' information if you write the code to do so.

So, it really depends on how your client is capable of receiving a 'message', such as providing a REST endpoint that the Lambda function can call.

Alternatively, the Lambda function could store status information 'somewhere' and the client could **poll** that location for status.

For example:

- When the client invokes the Lambda function (or calls something that invokes the function), it can **pass a randomized unique string**
- The Lambda function could **periodically update an Amazon S3 object**, stored in a particular bucket with that randomized string as the Key
- The client can **periodically poll the S3 object**, using the same Key, to retrieve status information

Comment: Or maybe a [serverless websocket from API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway).